# Jquery UI Datepicker doesn't load if input has value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have the following code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(function() {

    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});

});

</script>

<input type='text' id='datepicker' name='date' value='<?php echo $date_from_mysql_query;?>'>
```

If the field doesn't have any value, the Datepicker loads, if the field is completed, it doesn't load the Datepicker.

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tDaeH/ seems to be ok

Comment: it worked, i now tested it on my code and i need to see if my problem is actually generated by the css layout of my page, thank you!

Comment: and i solved the problem... in order to load datepicker plugin on multiple inputs, the input should be defined as a class='datepicker' and load the script as $("input.datepicker").datepicker({options});

Answer (score 0):

my problem actually was to make the datepicker to load on each  tagged via id, instead I used the class attribute and it worked marvelous, as I said 6 hrs ago.